# Django constraints - only users with specific role can have specific field set (not null)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, django-constraints

Trying to figure out if and how can I set conditional constraints like this:

Only users with `role=='client'` can have `User.broker` field not null.

Is it possible to do that using `Meta.contstraints` or a different mechanism that will take care of that?

User model:

```
class User...:
    role = CharField(...)
    broker = ForeignKey('User'...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint)

Comment: Omg, thanks. I know about that type of constraint but I didn't realize I can use it for this situation, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Alek Yo stated, I can use `CheckConstraint`

The working result:

```
constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(broker__isnull=True) | Q(role=RoleChoices.CLIENT),
                name="clients_only_can_have_broker",
            )
        ]
```